# Django form validation problem in clean method

Tags: django, validation, django-views, django-forms, validationerror

I'm new to the Django. Here, whenever I submit the form, validation error didn't appear even though I made mistake in filling form and also validation error isn't visible on the front end. Seek help soon as possible

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from testform import form
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def studentform(request):
    studentrecord=form.Student()
    data={'data':studentrecord}

    if request.method=='POST':
        studentrecord=form.Student(request.POST)
        if studentrecord.is_valid():
           print('validating')
           
           print('sname',studentrecord.cleaned_data['Name'])     
        
        
           print('sloc',studentrecord.cleaned_data['location'])
           print('smail',studentrecord.cleaned_data['mail'])                                   
       

    else:
        print('form is not valid')
        
    return HttpResponse('thanks for form filling')

return render (request,'testform/try.html',context=data)
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms

class Student(forms.Form):
    Name=forms.CharField()
    location=forms.CharField()
    mail=forms.EmailField()
    course=forms.CharField()


     def clean(self):
         total_clean=super().clean()
         inputname=total_clean['Name']
         if len(inputname)<5:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Type the name in below 5 letters')
    
        input_location=total_clean['location']
        if input_location =='Antartica':
           raise forms.ValidationError('Antartica is not valid')
    
         input_course=total_clean['course']

         if input_course not in ['python','java']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('select either python or java')
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Comment: is your message is printing "form is not valid" on console

Comment: @VinayVishwakarma Yes, It shows form is not valid all the time ! Can you check if any errors present

Comment: @VinayVishwakarma  <h1>WELCOME TO FORM FILLING</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" class="forms">

        {{data.as_p}}
        {% csrf_token %}
    

        <input type="submit" role="button" value="Submit">

    </form>

Comment: @VinayVishwakarma can you please tell where to add {{form.errors}}

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add form error tag in html files.
Added something like this.

```
<body>
   <!-- your html elements -->
      {{form.errors}}
</body>
```

Comment: Hey I added my code in your answer. Can you please tell where to add {{form.errors}}

Comment: You need to add this in your try.html file.

Comment: Still shows error

Answer (score 0):

The view logic always will show that the form was filled in correctly, even if it wasn't.

```
def studentform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        studentrecord = form.Student(request.POST)
        if studentrecord.is_valid():
            print('validating')
            print('sname', studentrecord.cleaned_data['Name'])
            print('sloc', studentrecord.cleaned_data['location'])
            print('smail', studentrecord.cleaned_data['mail'])
            return HttpResponse('thanks for form filling')
    else:
        studentrecord = form.Student()
    data = {'data': studentrecord}
    return render(request, 'testform/try.html', context=data)
```

In the form, you should also return the cleaned data:

from django import forms

```
from django import forms


class Student(forms.Form):
    # …

    def clean(self):
        total_clean = super().clean()
        inputname = total_clean['Name']
        if len(inputname) < 5:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Type the name in below 5 letters')

        input_location = total_clean['location']
        if input_location == 'Antartica':
            raise forms.ValidationError('Antartica is not valid')

        input_course = total_clean['course']

        if input_course not in ['python', 'java']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('select either python or java')
        return total_clean
```

Comment: Hey, It's still won't work.. Whenever I submit the form with wrong data, it shows (excute else part) form not valid in control panel. When I submit the form with correct data, it shows (excute if part) thanks for filling.. The main problem is, Whenever I enter the wrong data, it doesn't warn the user (what I mentioned statement in validation error) and also the error won't visible on front end

Comment: @PAVANKUMAR: the `else` part should bind with the `if request.method == 'POST'`, so not the one with `form.is_valid()`, it thus should be at the "outer" scope.

Comment: Still the same problem.. Error doesn't appear on the frontend.. whenever I submit the form with wrong data (it execute else), if I submitted with right data (it goes to other page which I coded). But whenever I type wrong data on the front end, validation error didn't appear on top of the form and also it didn't appear in control panel too

Comment: @PAVANKUMAR: it should *not* evaluate the `else`, that is why the indentation matters. It simply should stop at the `if studentrecord.is_valid()` line and then continue at the `data = ...` line. Do you have a debugger?

Comment: Yes, I do have django debugger toolbar